# Dukapress jQuery("form.product_update").livequery is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a wordpress site running Seduction theme and Dukapress. Once you add a product and reach the checkout page, the payment and discount button is not clickable. Chrome/Firebug throws the error jQuery("form.product_update").livequery is not a function

The site is available at : http://sunshinemountainvineyard.com/wine-shoppe/

Can somebody help me out here... I have no clue what is happening. I updates livequery to the latest version 1.1.1 and still no effect